# how to populate belongs_to model with Faker gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, faker

Current schema is this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160622075955) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "body"
    t.date     "date"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "posts", ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["first_name"], name: "index_users_on_first_name", using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["last_name"], name: "index_users_on_last_name", using: :btree

  add_foreign_key "posts", "users"
end
```

Trying to populate both models: Posts & Users

This is what I have for `seeds.rb`

```
20.times do |n| 
    a = User.new
    a.first_name = Faker::Name.first_name
    a.last_name = Faker::Name.last_name

    a.save

end

10.times do |n|
    b = Post.new
    b.title = Faker::Book.title
    b.body = Faker::Lorem.words(4, true)
    b.date = Faker::Time.between(DateTime.now - 1, DateTime.now) 

    b.save
end
```

It works for `User` but not for `Post`. How do I also populate `Post` as well?

**EDIT**

**Post's Model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :title, :body, presence: true
  validates :title, length: { maximum: 40 }
end
```

**User's Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
    validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true
end
```

**User's Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save 
      flash[:notice] = "User successfully added!"
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    render :edit
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
      redirect_to users_path
  end

  private 

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
    end

end
```

**Post's Controllers**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def new 
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.new
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.find(params[:id])
    render :edit
  end

  def create 
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.new(post_params)
    if @post.save 
      redirect_to user_path(@post.user)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update 
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to user_path(@post.user)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
      redirect_to users_path
    end

  private 

  private 
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :date)
    end
end
```

**EDIT TWO**

No errors shows up when I put `puts b.errors.inspect` in the `seeds.rb` file.

However, this is what shows up in the terminal when I run `rake db:seed`

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fa20d45aec8 @base=#<Post id: 1, title: "Surprised by Joy", body: "[\"sunt\", \"audentia\", \"pectus\", \"omnis\"]", date: "2016-06-26", user_id: nil, created_at: "2016-06-28 04:38:02", updated_at: "2016-06-28 04:38:02">, @messages={}>
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fa20d463a28 @base=#<Post id: 2, title: "The Golden Bowl", body: "[\"cohibeo\", \"verus\", \"ut\", \"corrupti\"]", date: "2016-06-27", user_id: nil, created_at: "2016-06-28 04:38:02", updated_at: "2016-06-28 04:38:02">, @messages={}>
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fa20d450220 @base=#<Post id: 3, title: "Such, Such Were the Joys", body: "[\"video\", \"tepesco\", \"stabilis\", \"esse\"]", date: "2016-06-26", user_id: nil, created_at: "2016-06-28 04:38:02", updated_at: "2016-06-28 04:38:02">, @messages={}>
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fa20d439d18 @base=#<Post id: 4, title: "Jesting Pilate", body: "[\"aut\", \"textor\", \"tui\", \"subiungo\"]", date: "2016-06-26", user_id: nil, created_at: "2016-06-28 04:38:02", updated_at: "2016-06-28 04:38:02">, @messages={}>
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fa20d428888 @base=#<Post id: 5, title: "Great Work of Time", body: "[\"cupiditas\", \"debeo\", \"decipio\", \"clementia\"]", date: "2016-06-27", user_id: nil, created_at: "2016-06-28 04:38:02", updated_at: "2016-06-28 04:38:02">, @messages={}>
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fa20d4192c0 @base=#<Post id: 6, title: "Look to Windward", body: "[\"totidem\", \"numquam\", \"ut\", \"amita\"]", date: "2016-06-26", user_id: nil, created_at: "2016-06-28 04:38:02", updated_at: "2016-06-28 04:38:02">, @messages={}>
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fa20d409d70 @base=#<Post id: 7, title: "Vile Bodies", body: "[\"cruentus\", \"adiuvo\", \"stella\", \"cimentarius\"]", date: "2016-06-26", user_id: nil, created_at: "2016-06-28 04:38:02", updated_at: "2016-06-28 04:38:02">, @messages={}>
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fa20d3fa6e0 @base=#<Post id: 8, title: "Consider the Lilies", body: "[\"dolor\", \"sumptus\", \"solutio\", \"theologus\"]", date: "2016-06-27", user_id: nil, created_at: "2016-06-28 04:38:02", updated_at: "2016-06-28 04:38:02">, @messages={}>
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fa20d3eaf38 @base=#<Post id: 9, title: "Terrible Swift Sword", body: "[\"aspernatur\", \"aegrus\", \"studio\", \"adstringo\"]", date: "2016-06-26", user_id: nil, created_at: "2016-06-28 04:38:02", updated_at: "2016-06-28 04:38:02">, @messages={}>
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fa20d3db920 @base=#<Post id: nil, title: "By Grand Central Station I Sat Down and Wept", body: "[\"earum\", \"rerum\", \"defessus\", \"sed\"]", date: "2016-06-26", user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:title=>["is too long (maximum is 40 characters)"]}>
```

Comment: Doesn't work? Any errors etc?

Comment: Does Post has a validation for user? after `b.save` add `puts b.errors.inspect` and update your question with the result. (Also you don't need the `|n|` variable since you're not using it)

Comment: Did you call `attr_accessor` for model attributes in Post model by any chance?

Comment: @HoMan, no, no errors. just doesn't populate.

Comment: @PetrGazarov, this is rails 4, so, it doesn't use `attr_accessor, but in the controller it does have it set in `post_params`

Comment: @dpedoneze, just updated question above with post's model. as you can see, it has validations

Comment: Rails 4 still uses attr_accessor fyi

Comment: @PetrGazarov, oh, ok, thanks! sorry for misunderstanding on my part. thought that since it has `post_params` there was no need for attr_accessor.

Comment: @dpedoneze, updated the `seeds.rb` with `puts b.errors.inspect` ... didn't generate any errors.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't :). If you put it, then you will have issues saving the model, hence my question.

Comment: right after `b.save` (and before the `end`) you have added the `puts b.errors.inspect` and it didn't show any error?!

Comment: How are you checking if the record was created?

Comment: @dpedoneze, not on the local page ... but i did finally realize it's showing in the terminal which i hadn't paid attention to ... let me paste it in question above

Comment: Yes, `puts` prints to the terminal. Since you're running the `seeds.rb`you don't need the controller code

Comment: @dpedoneze, just pasted it above.

Comment: Ok, the error is that the `Faker` some times are creating titles that are bigger than 40 characters. (look that in the example above, you've created 9 posts (because they have an ID) and only one failed (with the error message at the end)

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 I've posted an answer for your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that the `Faker` some times are creating titles that are **bigger than 40 characters**. (look that in the example above, you've created 9 posts (because they have an ID) and only one failed (with the error message at the end)

> @messages={:title=>["is too long (maximum is 40 characters)"]}

If you wanna use the Faker, you can cut the title.

```
b.title = Faker::Book.title[0..40] 
# it will get only the first 40 characters
```

This way you'll create 20 users with 1 post for each one. You can add another 5.times do ... end wrapping the Post creation so you'll have 5 post for each user. You can also create only one user and then set all post.user = User.first, so you'll have one user with lots of Posts.

```
20.times do
    user = User.new
    user.first_name = Faker::Name.first_name
    user.last_name = Faker::Name.last_name

    user.save

    post = Post.new
    post.title = Faker::Book.title[0..40]
    post.body = Faker::Lorem.words(4, true)
    post.date = Faker::Time.between(DateTime.now - 1, DateTime.now) 
    post.user = user
    post.save
end
```

Comment: hm, not sure what's going on ... but i did cut the title as per your answer ... and, yay, no errors shows up in the terminal ... but also no posts are created either. Only users are still created. Is my seeds.rb file correct?

Comment: How are you checking if the Posts are being created? try opening the console `rails c`, type `Post.count` and then run again the rake. Then check again the `Post.count` and see if the number changed. I'm 100% sure that they're being created since they have the `id` and the `created_at` attributes with values :)

Comment: Since you aren't setting a User for your created Posts you might not be able to reach them by calling `@user.post` (or any other user.method) since the Posts are "orphans".

Comment: to answer to your first comment, I went into rails console, and did post count. It came up with 10. Did rake again. Reloaded console. This time it came up with 20. So clearly they're being created. Per your second comment, how do I fix this? That means I wrote my `seeds.rb` incorrectly, yes? How do I write it in a way that posts are created along with the users?

Comment: You can set an user by doing `b.user = User.first` or you can create a new user for each post. That's going to depend on how you need the seed data.